# How to convert a hex-encoded string to a byte string in Perl?

Tags: perl, hex, packet

My original code is in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), but I need to convert it to Perl for some libraries that I don't have at my disposal in Python.

In Python I would do this:

```
packet=binascii.unhexlify('F0000000F6905C452001A8C0000000000160994E810FB54E0100DB0000000000000')
```

AND

This would create a string containing the binary representation of:

```
0xF0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xF6 0x90 0x5C 0x45 etc...
```

Now that my string is a byte array I can send it as the payload for my packet. How do I do it Perl?

Comment: `perldoc -f pack` is a good enough starting point. (Sorry no more details, bedtime.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) function for this.

Example:

```
$ perl -e 'print pack("H*", "303132616263"), "\n";'
012abc
```

Check out the [pack tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html).